# How To Change "Action and parameters", later on in your Google Action?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

So I was using [Gmail](https://assistant.google.com/services/a/uid/000000a4618d362f?hl=en-US) Google Action on my Assistant device and One thing that I found particularly intriguing was that when a user has given its message and email, after that assistant gives options for change or adding the message. That means on selecting those options, assistant will change the value of message entity or edit it as per user command, without re-enabling the whole intent.

My question is how can I implement this functionality in my Google Action. Is there any particular function made by Google that I can use or do I have to create one from scratch ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gmail's integration is a bit different than the way a third-party developer would do it, but you can [save user input from the current session](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/save-data) and modify it later on in your conversation. In your Action, this wouldn't be just one intent, but a few that would handle the work of modifying some session data and finally using that data to complete the user's original action.